# Databinding a list to a GridView. GridView can't find my property!

Tags: c#, data-binding, gridview, ienumerable

**Given:**

I have a class:

```
class MyObject
{
  public string Field1;
  public string Field2;
}
```

and the following code:

```
var list = SomeFunction(); // returns a valid List<MyObject>
gvMyList.DataSource = list;
gvMyList.DataBind(); // THIS THROWS AN EXCEPTION
```

And a GridView control in an aspx page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvMyList" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Field 1">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblCourse" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Field1") + " " + Eval("Field2") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Problem:**

So I know that if something implements `IEnumerable` then it can be passed to the `DataSource` property. As far as I know, if you pass `DataSource` a List then I should have access to the `MyObject`'s properties by using `Eval("Field1")` or `Eval("Field2")`. Thats not the case here. Instead I get an exception thrown:

`DataBinding: 'MyObject' does not contain a property with the name 'Field1'.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your class contains **Fields**, not **Properties**; You have to define Properties this way :

```
 class MyObject
    {
      public string Field1 { get; set; }
      public string Field2 { get; set; }
    }
```